# Give status based on unique value

Tags: excel, unique, lookup

[image: data sample]

Hi,

picture is sample data

Column A is BAG ID which contain duplicate
Column B is the item inside the Bag
Column C is status if item are received

at Column D want to show :
a) if Column C is "SIP" AND the bag id also show that any item inside same bag id is "sip" will show = "Bag & awb rcv"
b)if Column C is "not sip" AND the bag id also show that any item inside same bag id is "not sip" will show = "Bag not rcv"
c) if Column C is "NOT SIP" AND the bag id also show that any item inside same bag id is "sip" will show = "Bag rcv , awb SL"

THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Give a try on below formula-

```
=IF(C2="SIP","Bag & AWB rcv",IF(AND(C2="NOT SIP",COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER($C$2:$C$9,$A$2:$A$9=A2)))=1),"Bag not rcv","Bag rcv , awb SL"))
```

[image]

Comment: Its works! Thanks so much. Save all my time to search on correct formula. I've been trying all method but not works :(.

Comment: If it works then please tick mark the answer to close it.